# Should the Bootstrap media queries be saved in a css file or a js file?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using media queries for screen sizing, and I need help embedding the file into my HTML document. So, help?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> //This?
<script src="style.js"></script> //Or This?
```

Comment: media queries is css so you have to use it in style.css file.

Comment: Hi, You have to add media queries in css file, because in media queries we will write css.

Example of media queries

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

This code we will write in css file and this media queries will effect when screen size less than 500px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your style.js css media codes into the style.css 
CSS media queries are the part of .css extension files. You should not place it some other extension than .css 
Now a days there are preprocessor tool for css like .less, .sass, .scss you can use them in those extension files as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to use in css file only. Since the media queries are CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As indicate precedently, the media queries must be into a css file.

[Documentation for media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

For exemple for style a div element for responsive design :

```
@media (max-width: 700px){

    div{
      //For smartphone
    }
}
@media ( min-width: 701px and max-width: 900px{

    div{
        //For tablet
    }
}
@media ( min-width: 901px and max-width: 1200px{
    div{
        //For small destop
    }
}
@media ( min-width: 1201px){
    div{
        //For large desktop
    }
}
```